# Adding code to display image in the below code

Tags: html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to divide the page into 2 columns, one should contain these button's list and other should have an image. How can I change this code. Please help. :(

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="col-md-2 type btn btn-primary">Sales</button> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="col-md-2 type btn btn-primary">Stock</button> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary">Purchase </button> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary">Credit </button> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="button" class="col-md-2 btn btn-primary">Bank </button> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ShabnaKabeer is this what you wanted?http://jsfiddle.net/tribhuvanreddyramidi/0pkt1fn3/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <button type="button" class="type btn btn-primary">Sales</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="type btn btn-primary">Stock</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Credit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Bank</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">Images go here...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take this `row` as an example:

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
        <button type="button" class="col-md-6 type btn btn-primary">Sales</button> 

        <img src="example.jpg" alt="Image" class="col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```